# formdata in an ajax request returns Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation error

Tags: javascript, ajax

I dont understand why I get a `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation` error when trying to send this Ajax request

Code:

```
$( "#order_button" ).on( "click", function() {
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var address = $('#address').val();
    var co_address = $('#co_address').val();
    var city = $('#city').val();
    var image = $('#fileInput').prop('files')[0];

   updateDB(name, email, address, co_address, city, image);
});

    //update database with posted values
    function updateDB(name, email, address, co_address, city, image){
        var formData = new FormData();

        formData.append('image', image);
        formData.append('name', name);
        formData.append('email', email);
        formData.append('address', address);
        formData.append('co_address', co_address);
        formData.append('city', city);

        console.log(formData['name']);

        var data = {
            action: 'det_lilla_extra',
            formData: formData
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: data,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("success: " + data);
                $('.block-center').append('<i class="fa fa-check fa-4x" aria-hidden="true">');
                //clearInputfields();
                //successMessage();
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log("jqXHR: " + jqXHR);
                console.log("textStatus: " + textStatus);
                console.log("errorThrown: " + errorThrown);
            }
        });
    }
```

Also why does `console.log(formData['name']);` log `undefined?`. I know there is something grander here that im not understanding.

If I add `processData: false` then I get a sucess message. But In my php script I do a `var_dump($_POST)`. But nothing shows!

**EDIT:**

My code now looks like:

```
//update database with posted values
function updateDB(name, email, address, co_address, city, image){
    var formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('action', 'det-lilla-extra');
    formData.append('image', image);
    formData.append('name', name);
    formData.append('email', email);
    formData.append('address', address);
    formData.append('co_address', co_address);
    formData.append('city', city);

    console.log(formData['name']);

    $.ajax({
        url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("success: " + data);
            $('.block-center').append('<i class="fa fa-check fa-4x" aria-hidden="true">');
            //clearInputfields();
            //successMessage();
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("jqXHR: " + jqXHR);
            console.log("textStatus: " + textStatus);
            console.log("errorThrown: " + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

And my php script is simply: `echo var_dump($_POST);`.

But my ajax file that I recieve simply is a `0` why could this be?

Comment: Which line does the error come from?

Comment: I am not sure, since the js gets minified. This is the entire output: `jquery.js?ver=4.7.3:4 Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
    at e (jquery.js?ver=4.7.3:4)
    at dc (jquery.js?ver=4.7.3:4)
    at dc (jquery.js?ver=4.7.3:4)
    at Function.n.param (jquery.js?ver=4.7.3:4)
    at Function.ajax (jquery.js?ver=4.7.3:4)
    at updateDB (det_lilla_extra.js?ver=4.7.3:63)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (det_lilla_extra.js?ver=4.7.3:42)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery.js?ver=4.7.3:3)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.r.handle (jquery.js?ver=4.7.3:3)
​`

Comment: All my inputs looks like this. Just the `id` and the `placeholder` that is different. `<input class="form-control" type="text" id="city" placeholder="Stad" required autocomplete="off"/>`. Why do I need a name attribute? I am creating a new formData and appending a key value pair to it, right?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `formData['name']` can’t work. FormData doesn’t offer any special subscription support, so you are simply accessing the object’s properties — which don’t happen to have a `name` amongst them. You could use [FormData.get()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/get)

Secondly, what you are doing makes little sense. You put a FormData object into an object that you pass to jQuery as `data`. By default, i.e. if you don’t set `processData` to false, jQuery will try to convert `data` to a string. You told it to convert the given object to JSON (`dataType: 'json'`). But that cannot be done. Try this:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('test', 'abc');
JSON.stringify(formData);
```

which will give you an empty object: `{}`. This is likely also the reason, why you get this error.

You will either have to pass all data as pure JavaScript object to jQuery and let it serialise it to JSON, or put all data into the FormData object.

E.g.

```
var formData = new FormData();

formData.append('image', image);
formData.append('name', name);
formData.append('email', email);
formData.append('address', address);
formData.append('co_address', co_address);
formData.append('city', city);
formData.append('action' 'det_lilla_extra');  // Note this line

// Note that I removed your wrapper object

$.ajax({
    url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: formData,  // Note this change
    processData: false,  // Don’t forget this one
```

Comment: What I am trying to do is to send an image via my ajax request. So I tried doing what like what tyhey are doing here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23980733/jquery-ajax-file-upload-php

Comment: @vonhact I that case just put all information into the FormData object, don't wrap it into another object and pass it directly to jQuery (as `data` property). And set `processData: false`.

Comment: That is what I did before. But I get the same error. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43681291/how-do-i-send-images-in-an-ajax-request

Comment: @vonhact Please read my comment carefully. The code in the linked question passes a plain object to jQuery. You should, however, pass a FormData object *without* wrapping it into another object first to jQuery. Exactly like shown in the answer you linked to above.

Comment: Sorry! What I did now was remove the `data` object and appended `formData.append('action', 'det-lilla-extra'). Now I get a sucess message. But nothing gets logged in my php script. I will update my question.

Comment: @vonhact [`var_dump` returns `void`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) so `echo`ing it makes no sense. If you literally get `0` what you see is not the output from `var_dump` as it would give you `int(0)`.

Comment: Try setting the `contentType` property to `multipart/form-data` in the `$.ajax` options object. If that doesn’t help, it’s likely an issue with WordPress. Make sure your script/function gets actually called. I guess `action` is used for that purpose. Make sure WordPress can retrieve that value from the data.

Comment: @idmean Hi! Why exactly we can't mix `formData` into another `Object` with new attributes/properties? `append` did work! Thanks

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro Not sure I fully understand your question. You can, of course, store a FormData reference inside another object. And you can of course set random properties on FormData instances, but this doesn't serve any obvious purpose. Does any of this answer your question? Otherwise, please try to clarify.

Comment: @idmean Sorry! I tried to pass `data: {ajax:1, myData: myFormData}` and it didn't work, but when I `append` the Ajax value, or any other property, it works. Even using `processData: false` and/or `contentType: false`.  Thanks

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro Because FormData represents an "multipart/form-data" encoded payload. This by definition is just a list of key-value, or more specially, string-string pairs. There is no standardized way to represent an object structure with that. That's why append only accepts a string or blob. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append